# What is the best way to use NHibernate with three layer web application?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, data-access-layer

I have three layers web application (ORM, DAL, BLL). I used Entity Framework for my project but now I want try to use NHibernate. What is the best way to implement Repository and Unit of work patterns?

In my previous version of project ORM was represented by ORM's class models and DBContext class. I have DAL.Interfaces class library which consists of DTO, IRepository with CRUD operations and IUnitOfWork with Commit method.

DAL class library is an implementation of DAL.Interfaces. There are some parts of DAL:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public DbContext Context { get; private set; }

        public UnitOfWork(DbContext context)
        {
            Context = context;
        }

        public void Commit()
        {
            if(Context != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch(DbEntityValidationException exc)
                {
                    foreach (var eve in exc.EntityValidationErrors)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                            eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                        foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                        {
                            Debug.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                                ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                        }
                    }

                    throw;
                }
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if(!disposed)
            {
                if(disposing)
                {
                    // free managed objects
                }

                // free unmanaged objects

                Context?.Dispose();

                disposed = true;
            }
        }

        ~UnitOfWork()
        {
            if(!disposed)
            {
                Dispose(false);
            }
        }

        private bool disposed = false;
    }

public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
    {
        public UserRepository(DbContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
            this.unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
        }

        public void Create(DalUser entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

            User ormUser = entity.ToOrmUser();

            context?.Set<User>().Add(ormUser);
            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void Update(DalUser entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

            User ormUser = context?.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == entity.Id);

            if(ormUser != null)
            {
                ormUser.Nickname = entity.Nickname;
                ormUser.Password = entity.Password;
            }

            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public void Delete(DalUser entity)
        {
            if (entity == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

            User ormUser = context?.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == entity.Id);

            if (ormUser != null)
                context?.Set<User>().Remove(ormUser);

            unitOfWork.Commit();
        }

        public IEnumerable<DalUser> GetAll() => context?.Set<User>().ToList().Select(u => u.ToDalUser());

        public DalUser GetById(int id) => context?.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id)?.ToDalUser();

        public DalUser GetUserByNickname(string nickname) => context?.Set<User>().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Nickname == nickname)?.ToDalUser();

        private readonly DbContext context;
        private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;
    }
```

All of my dependencies were resolved by Ninject. 
ISession of NHibernate already realized Unit of work pattern. Should I still implement this interface? Where I should creates instance of Configuration, ISessionFactory and ISession? Could you tell me how my repositpry should look?
How my architecture should look in this case?

Comment: not completely a duplicate, but take a look at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484332/what-is-the-best-way-to-manage-transaction-with-nhibernate-repository/36489959#36489959